# Agent-Pool "default" not available for new build pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We're running an on premise Azure DevOps Server which was recently updated from TFS 2017. Today I noticed that the "default" agent pool (which we use for our buld agents) is not available for new build pipelines of new projects while existing projects and pipelines are working fine.

Has anyone an idea how to fix this and make the "default" pool available to new build pipelines?

Comment: Are the new pipelines in the same team project like the old?

Comment: Yes they are because we only use one collection

Comment: In one collection could be a few team projects, do you work in one team project?

Comment: No, sorry. The new pipeline is a new project.

Comment: I just checked an old project and it was not affected by this issue.

Comment: When you add the project, is your login information correct? Either using Oauth or any other account for the repo.

Comment: I think yes. But when I create a new pool its available to my new pipeline. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found it myself. I had to add the agent-pool to my project by going to Project settings > Agent pools, click new agent pool, select "Base it on an existing organization agent pool" and select the "default" agent pool from organization agent pool.

Comment: This setting is required only in the case when we created Agent pool with "auto-provisioned" off.